# Median of a function of a vector without dynamic allocation cpp

Tags: c++

I have some custom struct:

```
customStruct{
float x;
float y;
float u;
float v;
}
```

and it is held in some internal vector with a pointer. One of my methods there is the following code:

```
float calcInitialVal(const myType::ptr_vector<customStruct>& points){
  std::vector<float> tmp;
  int numPoints = points.size();
  tmp.reserve(2*numPoints);
  for(const auto& itr: points){
    float val_x = /*do some arithmetic operation involving itr.x and itr.u*/;
    tmp.push_back(val_x);
    float val_y = /*do some arithmetic operation involving itr.y and itr.v*/;
    tmp.push_back(val_y);
  }

  nth_element(tmp.begin(), tmp.begin()+numPoints, tmp.end());
  return *(tmp.begin() + numPoints);
}
```

Essentially, this applies a function (int the 'do some arithmetic' part) to all elements of `points`, then finds the middle element of the resulting vector, if it was sorted (sort of median?).

A more specific example:

```
float calcInitialVal(const myType::ptr_vector<customStruct>& points){
  float s = 3;
  float x0 = 5;
  float y0 = 1.5;
  std::vector<float> tmp;
  int numPoints = points.size();
  tmp.reserve(2*numPoints);
  for(const auto& itr: points){
    float val_x = itr.u - s*(itr.x - x0);
    tmp.push_back(val_x);
    float val_y = itr.v - s*(itr.y - y0);;
    tmp.push_back(val_y);
  }

  nth_element(tmp.begin(), tmp.begin()+numPoints, tmp.end());
  return *(tmp.begin() + numPoints);
}
```

My problem is the dynamic allocation of the `tmp` vector. This function can be called with a `points` vector without any prior knowledge of its length. Is there a way to achieve the exact same result without dynamically allocating memory at runtime?

Comment: The whole idea of vector is that it is dynamic in size. And your input is already a vector so it is not possible to do anything at compile time to avoid dynamic allocation of tmp. 
Only if you can know all the sizes at compile time then it is possible to avoid dynamic allocation.

Comment: Nothing occurs to me.

Comment: Don't do this `numPoints>>1`, it reduces readability, make it `numPoints / 2`, trust the compiler intelligence.

Comment: "finds the middle element of the resulting vector", `nth_element(points.begin(), points.begin()+n, points.end());
}` - typo?

Comment: Why can you use `std::nth_element`(?) on iterators to a const vector at all? That's inconsistent with `std::vector`, since `std::nth_element` reorders the array. If you're willing to use a approach not guaranteed to be optimal and are allowed to reorder the input vector, you should be able to use a quick-sort like approach and just do the recursion on one of the partitions...

Comment: @273K it was a typo. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Then `numPoints>>1` is not a middle element of `tmp`, it must be just `numPoints`.

Comment: `*(tmp.begin() + n);` is a very strange long hard to read expression of `tmp[n]`.

Comment: Of course you could go through all the values counting the smaller ones and the equal ones until you find the one in the middle, but that would be suboptimal performance-wise...

Comment: @273K, I have this method twice in order to initialize two different procedures. Once it is an `x,y` issue and once it is another single element of the struct. I copied from both by mistake. I think it is good now. regarding your comments on the `>>` operation and the indexing, this is simply the way the code was originally implemented. I do agree with your comments.